# Angular.js Controller Naming Approach

Tags: angularjs, controller, modal-dialog

I am developing an app in Angular v1.x, with the following scenario.

1. A user (seller) can offer an item to a buyer
2. A user (buyer) can accept or decline the offer

When a user clicks to add an offer (1) or (2) decide on an offer I am using a Modal service injected into my app. An example would be:

```
app.controller('SampleController', ["$scope", "ModalService", function($scope, ModalService) {

  $scope.showAModal = function() {

    // Just provide a template url, a controller and call 'showModal'.
    ModalService.showModal({
      templateUrl: "yesno/yesno.html",
      controller: "YesNoController"
    }).then(function(modal) {
      modal.element.modal();
      modal.close.then(function(result) {
        $scope.message = result ? "You said Yes" : "You said No";
      });
    });

  };

}]);
```

For each modal I can set the controller used. My initial thoughts were to have a single "offersController" used by both modals which would handle the logic for both cases. But for each case different api calls to a REST service to get initial view variables must be made. For example:

- when a buyer wants to see all Offers received a call is made,
- when in the first scenario a user is making an offer the current offers are not required

I don't see a way of isolating the logic within the same controller and making the call depending on the cases I have.

So should I use two controllers, if so what would be a suitable naming convention? I thought to have "offersAddController" and "offersDecideController". But I am not sure this is correct since "add" and "decide" are actions and it doesn't feel right to have an action name in my controller.

It almost seems as if my controller are them selves actions which now makes me doubt my approach. Should I be approaching this differently?

Comment: Hi Alan, take a look at my answer and let me know what do you think. I may not be entirely correct but I tried to explain as per my understanding of your question. Feel free to put any comments on my answer and we can discuss it further and modify my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you description

1. for buyer , we need to get some good amount of data as we are fetching all the offers that the buyer already have.
2. For seller, we are not making any API calls (may be we can make an API call where we can show the *all the offers that the seller has made* , or something like that)

Now, if we look at **Single Responsibility** principal of **SOLID**, we should make 2 separate controllers as there is much more going on than just asking the user(buyer/seller) about their choice , i.e., we are also showing all the offers that they have. It would also help us to expand our respective 
code in future, in case we plan on manipulating the data before showing on UI.

> so, it would be wise to have better `html` file name something like `offerConfirmation.html`. Because,  we are showing the offers as well. Currently you have used `yesno.html`.

For Controller names, I think we can use something like:

1. `BuyerConfimationController`
2. `SellerConfirmationController`

I chose this name because the name like `offersAddController` and `offersDecideController` is not self explanatory for some new developer unless he's aware that the **Seller** can `add` and **Buyer** will `decide`. (although it may sound obvious) .

I know it may sound obvious to know `add` and `decide`  for a user(seller/buyer) but there is a good chance that the roles might get more complicated in future (or if we were dealing some special domain related users,  we need to understand **User Roles** before touching the code). Keeping controller names as explicit as possible would help any new developer to directly jump to specific controllers and make necessary changes.

Comment: so is it the correct Angular approach to have two distinct controllers instead of one? It seems that the controller names are in some ways describing actions. Is this how Angular works. I am from a PHP background, I would expect the controller to be simply the controller for a model - offersController. Is this a convention not used in Angular?

Comment: Yeah, there is no as such standard naming convention but as a good practice , it should explain what action will it be controlling.

Answer (score 1):

As per the naming convention of the controller, it would be better if you choose a name which literally describes the controller functionality.
I recommend you to choose the controller name as [action][Type][Controller].
In this case, AddOffersController and DecideOffersController will be a suitable name.